# create a DataFrame from for loop

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have defined a function to create a dataframe, but I get two lists in each column, how could I get each element of the list as a separate row in the dataframe as shown below.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def function():
  result = []
  
  for i in range(0, len(a)):
    number = [i for i in a]
    operation = [8*i for i in a]

    result.append({'number': number, 'operation': operation})

    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['number','operation'])
        
        return df
    
function()
```

Result:

```
       number          operation
0   [1, 2, 3, 4]    [8, 16, 24, 32]
```

What I really want to:

```
            number         operation
    0          1              8
    1          2              16
    2          3              24 
    3          4              34
```

Can anyone help me please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are twofold, firstly you are pushing the entire list of values (instead of the "current" value) into the result array on each pass through your for loop, and secondly you are overwriting the dataframe each time as well. It would be simpler to use a list comprehension to generate the values for the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
 
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 
def function():
    result = [{'number' : i, 'operation' : 8*i} for i in a]
    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    return df
 
print(function())
```

Output:

```
   number  operation
0       1          8
1       2         16
2       3         24
3       4         32
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def function():
    
  
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
            number = [i for i in a]
            operation = [8*i for i in a]

    v=np.rot90(np.array((number,operation)))
    result=np.flipud(v)

    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['number','operation'])
        
    return df
    
print (function())

   number  operation
0       1          8
1       2         16
2       3         24
3       4         32
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just replace `number = [i for i in a]` with `number = a[i]` and `operation = [8*i for i in a]` with `operation = 8 * a[i]`

(FYI: No need to create pandas dataframe inside loop. You can get same output with pandas dataframe creation outside loop)

Refer to the below code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def function():
    
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        number = a[i]
        operation = 8*a[i]
        result.append({'number': number, 'operation': operation})

    df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['number','operation'])    
    return df

function()

number  operation
0   1   8
1   2   16
2   3   24
3   4   32
```